# XML - I need help getting at the ID property value

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion 7 and am new at parsing XML.

I am trying to get at the ID property and extract its value.

```
<cfset newRate = StructNew()>
<cfset newRate.Carrier = "USPS">
<cfset newRate.Code = Service[i].ID.XmlAttribute>
<cfset newRate.Descr = Service[i].SvcDescription.XmlText>
<cfset newRate.Price = Service[i].Postage.XmlText>
```

I have tried every combination I can think of to get at the ID property, but nothing works.

Can you help?

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

This returns an array:

```
<cfset newRate.Code = xmlSearch(Service[i], "/@ID")>
```

You can view the real XML here;

https://secure.thelowertowngroup.com/steinair/usps/usps_rates_international.cfm

Comment: What you've posted is not valid XML.

Comment: `<cfset newRate.Code = Service[i].ID.XmlAttribute.xmlText>` ?

Comment: @Jim Garrison - Service[ i ] is the XML.  Hard to say whether or not it's valid without seeing it :)

Comment: I have included a link to the XML.

Comment: OK how about `Service[i].XMLAttributes.ID` ? (doing this as comments rather than answers since I'm WAG'ing it a bit)

Comment: You can see the property ID that I am trying to get at:  https://secure.thelowertowngroup.com/steinair/usps/usps_rates_international.cfm

Comment: Yes, I saw it in the link.  Does my most recent comment not work?  Seems there's an XMLAttributes node, which contains a struct with a key of "ID".  If it doesn't work, tell me it doesn't work and tell me what error it returned.

Comment: No. It didn't work. I am going to hold off on this for a while to test it.  Thanks!

Comment: Link generates a CF exception. Suggest copying XML and adding to question.

Comment: That link just errors with:

Variable noReg is undefined.
 
The error occurred in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\steinair.net\httpdocs\usps\usps_rates_international.cfm: line 135

133 : 
134 : 
135 :         <cfset newRate.Descr = trim(noReg(Service[i].SvcDescription.XmlText))>

Answer (score 0):

Am needing to do this a bit blind as we can't see your XML (as per my earlier comment, the link you provide is broken).

However... consider THIS code:

```
<cfxml variable="x">
    <aaa>
        <bbb id="1">
            <id>2</id>
            <ccc></ccc>
            <ccc></ccc>
            <ccc id="3">
                <ddd></ddd>
                <ddd id="4"></ddd>
            </ccc>
        </bbb>
    </aaa>
</cfxml>

<cfoutput>
    #x.aaa.bbb.xmlAttributes["id"]#<br />
    #x.aaa.bbb.id.xmlText#<br />
    #x.aaa.bbb.ccc[3].xmlAttributes["id"]#<br />
    <cfset a = xmlSearch(x, "/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd[@id]")>
    #a[1].xmlAttributes["id"]#<br />
</cfoutput>
```

There's some options for fetching IDs.  Do any of them help?

Comment: I can't work on this till Monday, but I think I was looking for this:  <cfset a = xmlSearch(x, "/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd[@id]")>  I'll let you know.  Thanks!